# How to calculate the coordinate vector with respect to a particular basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to calculate the coordinate vector of $M=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with respect to the basis 
$$B=\left \{ A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, B= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, C= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, D= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \right \} $$

How can I do that, with a different basis from the canonical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find constants $x,y,z,w$ such that $M=xA+yB+zC+wD$. Comparing each entry you have 4 equations and 4 variables, in this case this shouldn't be dfficult to solve since a lot of entries from $A,B,C,D$ are $0$.